# how can i connect client and server without local IP or localhost Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

i have a client and server program, i mean client is communicating to the server, but my server is my same system, (localhost)..
but i want to ping other system instead of localhost, to do this i need to change the localhost to that system ip-address but that system is not connected to my system(neither wired nor wireless). but that system has access to internet??
how can i connect or ping to that system..??`
**CLIENT CODE**:
    import socket
    import os
    import subprocess
    import time as y
    import time
    s = socket.socket()
    host = '192.168.1.190'
    port = 9999

**Server Code:**
    global host
    global port
    global s
    host = ''
    port = 9999
    s = socket.socket()

Comment: *...but i want to ping other system...* I'm confused, what other system? *...192.168.1.190...' That is not a valid IP address on the internet, so your setup must be more complicated than you have communicated, perhaps simply a NAT or perhaps something else.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really think you can use socket to reach a host with "internet" , because when you're connected to internet your ip adress is converted to another public one using NAT ( hosts are defined by port numbers ), and it is hidden so the remote applications cannot reach you directly , there is what we call DMZ which protect your machine , so the only way to use sockets is to send it to hosts on same network

Comment: then how can i do this if i want to connect through internet i am using my local ip address here but how can i do this over internet

Comment: @TahirSaeed sadly that's not possible through internet , an that's why web applications are used ( sending and getting data to/from a server ) , to explain you why , for example if u try that address '192.168.1.190' , that's not the real address of the host , its just the address of the router that is linking the host with internet with a port number

Comment: brother but there will be a way to do so like web application can you please explain how can i create web app;ication and how will it work over internet how to link chatting program with it ?

Comment: @TahirSaeed , you can create a web application for chatting , it will be linked to a database , actually this is how Facebook and many other applications work  , on this web application any user will have an id and password , so when a user1 sends a message to a user2 , this message will be saved in the database , and the user2 will extract his message from that database and send messages in the same way .